# Keep the page unlocked after ModalPopupExtender displays

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender

I am able to display the modal popup using the following code

```
<asp:scriptmanager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:scriptmanager>

<asp:button id="Button1" runat="server" text="Button" />

<cc1:modalpopupextender id="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" 
    cancelcontrolid="btnCancel" okcontrolid="btnOkay" 
    targetcontrolid="Button1" popupcontrolid="Panel1" 
    popupdraghandlecontrolid="PopupHeader" drag="true" 
    backgroundcssclass="ModalPopupBG">
</cc1:modalpopupextender>

<asp:panel id="Panel1" style="display: none" runat="server">
    <div class="HellowWorldPopup">
                <div class="PopupHeader" id="PopupHeader">Header</div>
                <div class="PopupBody">
                    <p>This is a simple modal dialog</p>
                </div>
                <div class="Controls">
                    <input id="btnOkay" type="button" value="Done" />
                    <input id="btnCancel" type="button" value="Cancel" />
        </div>
        </div>
</asp:panel>
```

But I need to keep the page active and let the users to keep making selections on the page without closing the modal popup. Is this possible?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that the modal dialog from the AJ toolkit allows this.

While I have in the past used the modal dialog from the AJ toolkit, the lack of being able to position the dialog on the screen where I want was over time became a deal breaker.

The only real bonus points of using that AJ Toolkit popup is not having to write any JavaScript.

Other then not having to write JavaScript, over time I moved over to the jQuery.UI dialog due to additional features.

The jQuery.UI dialog works better then the AJ Toolkit one, and even works better then the bootstrap dialog and does so with less markup.

Only real downside of the jQuery.UI dialog is by default it looks like something from the early 2000 web days style wise (it looks poor).

However, with a bit of CSS work, it comes out nice.

The jQuery.UI dialog also supports drag around on the page better then does the AJ Toolkit dialog.

Your question here is thus another example and reason why going with the jQuery.UI dialog is a better choice.

The jQuery.UI dialog has both "modal" = true/false setting, ideal for this question.

Hence this example and markup:

Markup:

```
<asp:Button ID="cmdTest" runat="server" Text="Show my pop up"
    OnClientClick="showpop(this);return false;"
    CssClass="btn" />
<br />
<br />

<label>First Name</label> <br />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <br /> <br />

<label>LastName Name</label> <br />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLast" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <br /> <br />

<label>Hotel Name</label> <br />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtHotelName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


<div id="mypopdiv" style="display:none;padding:20px" >
    <h3>My Test popup area</h3>
    <label>My Notes Area</label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" runat="server"
        TextMode="MultiLine" Height="139px" Width="354px"
        ></asp:TextBox>
</div>

<script>

    function showpop(btn) {
        myDialog = $("#mypopdiv")
        myDialog.dialog({
            title: "Page notes",
            sizable: true,
            appendTo: "form",
            width: "400",
            modal: false,
            dialogClass: "dialogWithDropShadow",
            position: { my: 'left top', at: 'right bottom', of: btn },
            buttons: {
                Close: function () {
                    myDialog.dialog('close');
                }
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

And the result is this:

[image]

Note how I can freely open, close, move around the dialog, and am freely able to edit text in the popup, or edit + use any other control on the existing page.

## Edit: jQuery and jQuery.UI via CDN

So, to reference jQuery and jQuery.UI, hence this :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>


    <style type="text/css">
         .dialogshadow
         {
             -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);  
             -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
         }
    </style>
```

And then your .dialog call looks like this:

```
        <script>

            function showpop(btn) {
                myDialog = $("#mypopdiv")
                myDialog.dialog({
                    title: "Page notes",
                    sizable: true,
                    appendTo: "form",
                    width: "400",
                    modal: false,
                    dialogClass: 'dialogshadow',
                    position: { my: 'left top', at: 'right bottom', of: btn },
                    buttons: {
                        Close: function () {
                            myDialog.dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        </script>
```

Now, I like this shadow class somewhat better and is the one I used for this code:

```
<style>
    .dialogWithDropShadow {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

        .dialogWithDropShadow
        .ui-dialog-titlebar {
            background: white;
            border: none;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

        .dialogWithDropShadow
        .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
            display: none
        }
</style>
```

The above results in this:

[image]

So, I "hide" the "x" to close in the upper right corner. If you remove this:

```
        .dialogWithDropShadow
        .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
            display: none
        }
```

Then you get this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. When I try this and click on the button, the page just refreshes and popup does not open. Which version of jquery do I need to reference for this?

Comment: To be clear I have a master page head section where I placed the jquery references and scripts and the button is in child aspx page.

Comment: You need both jquery and jquery.ui.  so we all have jQuery but you will have to add/install jquery.ui

Comment: Yes, I am referencing both  in the master file. <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: see my edit, you may well have not included the default .css style sheet which is required.

Comment: Thank you. Still not working for me, button still does the same. Just refreshes the page and jquery dialog doesn't open. However I found an alternative solution to meet my goal. Followed the below code. https://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/10/jquery-floating-div-on-page-scroll.html

Comment: drag in a html button (input) and try this:             <input id="Button1" type="button" value="test"
                onclick="showpop(this);return false;"
                />
  -- now you can load the page, hit f12 (browser debug tools), and choose the console tab. Now click the button - do you see any javaScript errors? Better yet, try a 100% new test page, and paste in my sample markup.